# View disappearing inside ScrollView when 'fillViewport' is not set to true

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-scrollview

I have recently implemented the `WheelIndicatorView` from the repository below:

https://github.com/dlazaro66/WheelIndicatorView

Here is the XML code below for my layout that utilises the new `View`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="@string/heading"
            android:id="@+id/heading"
            style="@style/Heading" />

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/heading"
            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:entries="@array/spinner_values" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/spinner">

            <com.dlazaro66.wheelindicatorview.WheelIndicatorView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/wheel_indicator_view"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                app:itemsLineWidth="13dp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="@string/total"
                    android:id="@+id/total"
                    style="@style/Heading" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_more"
            android:tint="@color/White"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/DarkViolet"
            app:fabSize="normal"
            app:elevation="6dp"
            app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Unfortunately I am currently fighting between two issues. The first issue is that if I remove the `android:fillViewport="true"` from the `ScrollView`, then the `WheelIndicatorView` completely disappears. However if I do add that variable to the `ScrollView` then although the `WheelIndicatorView` displays on the screen, the 'scrollable' view is no longer actually scrollable. Where am I going wrong and how can I resolve this layout issue permanently?

Edit - Here is the simplest layout I can propose to detail this issue (multiple `WheelIndicatorView`s above one another in a `ScrollView`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.dlazaro66.wheelindicatorview.WheelIndicatorView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/wheel_indicator_view"
            app:itemsLineWidth="13dp" />

        <com.dlazaro66.wheelindicatorview.WheelIndicatorView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/wheel_indicator_view2"
            app:itemsLineWidth="13dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```